# Download a single file from GitHub by release

Tags: git, github

I've managed the list all the tags (or releases which is kind of the same thing on GitHub) for a repo and now I would like to download a single file from each of them.

The reason is I want to track the differences between them.

I have been told to use

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<user>/<repository>/<hash>/main.c
```

which doesn't seem to work. Here is the actual query I used:

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openssl/openssl/ab2de707f72a82e0294bae08cca97455b635a656/crypto/rsa/rsa_gen.c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you used is correct, but `<hash>` must be a valid commit ID.
You can look up the commit ID of a specific release on this page: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases.

Comment: Is there a way to do that automatically? I mean retrieving the release commit IDs?

Comment: This can be achieved using git. After cloning the repository, you can list tags with `git tag -l`, and find the ID of the commit pointed by the tag with `git rev-list -1 <tag>`. It can also be done using [GitHub's Releases API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/), or by parsing the releases pages yourself.